# Value structs in DTOs in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I there a way to get proper serialization of structs in DTO's or better yet have the framework somehow treat the structs as dto's.

I have been informed of the JsConfig.TreatValueAsRefTypes value but that would just work for json am I right? what about xml, soap, mq ect...
I simply want to use the structs I have an not have to map them to dto's which for my project would take years...

On the side not I also cant figure out what im doing wrong with JsConfig.TreatValueAsRefTypes the compiler seems to think its being called in static context:
  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just [committed a change](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/c48f2ebec60f55818e43615e449c0d9be67ab805) (available in the next release) that makes `JsConfig<T>.TreatValueAsRefType` as static so you can now serialize struct types as a reference type, e.g:

```
public struct UserStruct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

JsConfig<UserStruct>.TreatValueAsRefType = true;

var dto = new UserStruct { Id = 1, Name = "foo" };

dto.ToJson().Print(); //= {"Id":1,"Name":"foo"}

dto.ToJsv().Print();  //= {Id:1,Name:foo}

dto.ToXml().Print();
```

ServiceStack uses .NET's XML DataContractSerializer (which is also used in SOAP) which already serializes structs as expected with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserStruct xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceStack.Text.Tests">
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>foo</Name>
</UserStruct>
```

You can also use the static API to register struct types using the non-generic API:

```
JsConfig.TreatValueAsRefTypes.Add(typeof(UserStruct));
```

Comment: #nythz Thank you for explanation, is the last line currently available? TreatValueAsRefTypes is internal in the version that I'm using... Am I doing something wrong?
If not, when is the next release? Would I be safe to pull the latest and run with that till the next release is out?

Comment: Yeah its safe to pull latest and rebuild the solution, that's all I do for deployment. It will be in the next release, I plan to deploy next weekend after I get back from holiday.

Comment: Do the structs have to be defined in the same assembly as the IService that will be returning them or registered with the container?
I finally got everything wired up and the service returns empty json objects? for xml i get "invalid xmlChar"?
Am i missing a ContractNamespace or something?
These structs come from a native cli assambly and have other structs and arrays embedded in them.

Comment: There's no requirement that they exist in the same dll. Though still only public properties get serialized.

Comment: Did some digging.. it seems that the only properties of structs actually get serialized. Is there any way to get public fields as well?

Comment: Nope sorry, ServiceStack serializers only support public properties by design.